# How to keep manageable pages after turning off page shuffle?

Tags: adobe-indesign

I've seen this tutorial http://philippaberrysmith.wordpress.com/2011/09/09/how-to-get-page-numbering-to-start-where-you-want-it-in-indesign-cs5/ but after turning off the page shuffle option when I try to insert a page between 2 sections strange things occures such as adding a third page to a 2-page spread or adding the new spread but the page is on the right instead of left

thanks for help (:

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turning off the page shuffle means that InDesign will no longer maintain the spreads automatically thus allowing you to add or move pages wherever you want.

You can drag your “strange” pages to proper positions in the `Pages` panel keeping a close eye on how the pointer changes - this will give you a hint where you are currently placing your page.

[image]